# What kind of content type I have to post for file upload

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

how to upload a file from jquery to a resteasy service which consumes multipart/form-data?

i tried the following but it always return failure. It shows unsupported media type.

```
jQuery("#Upload").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: serviceurl,
        type: 'POST',
        //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data: {
            file: filename
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
            return false;
        },
        error: function (data, status) {
            alert("failue");
            alert(status);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Always add what you have done so far, otherwise it will give an impression that you have done nothing to get a solution, and you will get downvoted and eventually banned...so alter the post as soon as possible to get upvoted, and pls do not delete the post..that does more harm.

Answer (score 0):

You can post it like this:

```
    function uploadFile() {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("fileToUpload", FILE TO BE UPLOADED);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
        xhr.open("POST", "URL TO POST");
        xhr.send(fd);
    }
```

And if you want you can make use of the listeners added (uploadProgress, uploadComplete, uploadFailed, and uploadCanceled), else neglect the lines.

1. Replace the `FILE TO BE UPLOADED` with the file to be uploaded.
2. Replace the `URL TO POST` with the URL to be posted to.

> Let me know if you need more assistance and if it was helpful mark it
>   as one. Thank you.

Comment: @Telthien: I need upvotes to get rid of a ban [i cant post questions here], and users forget to upvote when they get find the answers useful. So the last line was relevant. But thanks for the edit.

Comment: It doesn't really belong there, but if you insist.

Comment: @A J: FormData method is not supported in IE Browser :(